# Response from Facebook apprequest API contains invalid Facebook account IDs? (javascript sdk)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I've got a nice little Facebook app going, but I seem to be having an odd issue.

According to the documentation, when you call the Facebook apprequests API to send a game request to another user you should receive a response which contains a `to` parameter, which will be a list of facebook IDs. Now this is pretty much what happens for me, only the facebook IDs don't seem to be correct. They look like facebook IDs in that they're a long-ish string of numbers, but when I try to look at them in the graph explorer, they return nothing but an error message saying the object doesn't exist. When I'm testing I know what the IDs are of the friends I'm inviting and they don't match what I'm receiving back from the response object, and I don't see what these numbers are or where they're coming from. It's not the `request_id` parameter, I know that for sure.

Now my only thought is that it has to do with my app still being in sandbox mode, but I did try to switch it to production mode for a few minutes and test but it still did the same thing. The only thing I can think is that maybe it takes some time for the change to take effect, so tomorrow I'll try to switch it to production for a little longer and see if that does anything, but otherwise I'm stumped. This feature is really important too, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what app did you select in the api explorer while testing those ids? the api explorer app or your own one?

Comment: btw, is it about a game or an app? and do you know about "app scoped ids"?

Comment: Ahh okay, I had been selecting API explorer app instead of my app. Selecting my app now allows me to view the correct graph explorer result. The only thing now is that the IDs in `to` still don't match the canonical facebook IDs, so resupplying the values from `to` into the `exclude_ids` parameter doesn't seem to work.

It's set as a game. I'll have to look into app scoped IDs.

Comment: that was not my question, IS it a game or did you only set it to the game category? those are app scoped IDs for sure. it´s alright, you can use them, they are just bound to the app.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the comments:

- Select YOUR App in the API Explorer, instead of the "API Explorer" App.
- IDs are "App Scoped", which means they are only available for your specific App. They can be used like global IDs though, you don´t need the "real" IDs anymore and you can´t get them anyway.
- If your App is NOT a game, don´t use apprequests. Those are for "games with a Canvas implementation" only.